# how to assign a value to text box when we are select a value from the dropdown

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am using Mvc3 and my view engine is razor and  also writing jquery in my view,
how can i assign a value to text box based on select a value from drop down list.

example:

if i am selected EmpId form drop down then the text box will be fill with Employee Name form same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#Emplist").change(function(){
    $.ajax({
    url:"@Url.Action("GetEmployeeName","Employee")",
    data:{
         id: $(this).val()
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#EmployeeName").val(data);
    }
   })
})


<select id="Emplist"><option value='1'>Mehmet</option></select>



public string GetEmployeeName(int id){
     var emp = //Get Employee by Id
     return emp.Name
}
```

Comment: iam not getting you this is my view                               <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ddlApplication").change(function () {
            var idModel = $(this).val();
                    alert(idModel)
         
            $.getJSON("/sree/Sree", { id: idModel },
 function (carData) {
   var idModel = $("#ddlApplication option:selected").text();
    $("#textbox").val(idModel);
  });
 });
});in my controller i am writing a query

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your OnChange event, make an ajax call and then populate the textbox with the response. You can pass a json result as response, and handle all the parameters you want.

```
$('#dropDownId').change(function() 
{
    empId = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ EmpId: empId }),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Result) {
                $("#txtId").val(data.EmpName);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample example, where **dropDownBoxId** is the id of the dropDownBox and **txtBoxId** is the id of Textbox.

```
        $(function () {
        $('#dropdownBoxId').change(function () {
            // gets the value from the drop down box
            var selected = $("#dropdownBoxId option:selected").text();

            // puts the value into the textbox
            var txtBox = document.getElementById('txtBoxId');
            txtBox .value = selected

        });
    });
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but corresponding id only binding to text box